# ERROR:either bundle id or package name / hash are invalid, unknown, malformed

Tags: react-native, linkedin-api

I am using `react-native-linkedin-login` npm when clicking on login button of linkedin app then alert generate like it

> ERROR:either bundle id or package name / hash are invalid, unknown, malformed

I have have entered the right hash key and package name in linkedin developer account which generate using this command on terminal

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

i am working on react native applicaton social login

Comment: have you ever get answer for this ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, any solution anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not modifying the APK in any way.

After signing the APK (debug build) I was manually editing the APK contents and this was causing the LinkedIn social login app to get suspicious. It seems like it validates your app's signing key. For me this was failing because I had mangled the APK.